# Quotient of manifolds by groups and embeddings

Tags: gr.group-theory, cv.complex-variables, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X_1\to X_2$ be a closed submanifold. Let $\rho:G_1\to G_2$ be a closed Lie subgroup. Let $G_1$ acts on $X_1$ and $G_2$ on $X_2$ and suppose $f$ is $\rho$-equivariant. I would like to get a morphism $\overline{f}:X_1/G_1\to X_2/G_2$ and conditions for $\overline{f}$ to be also a closed embedding. Do you know a reference where I can find this situation treated, in the category of analytic manifolds(or algebraic varieties)?

Comment: The group $G_1$ acts on $X_2$ via $\rho$ and it seems to be implicit in the question that the map $f$ is $G_1$-equivariant.

Comment: Dear Victor and Workitout, Thanks for clarifying (what should have been obvious to me anyway!).  My previous comment was premised on a slightly strange (on my part) misconstruing of the question, and so I have deleted it.   